# Quelle est la relation entre le « coup de sonde » et le « sondage » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, synonymes, mathématiques, origine-ou-raison

Dans un article au sujet de la [*Loi sur l'immatriculation des armes à feu*](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cs/I-0.01) (du Québec) on peut lire que :

> Le collectif PolySeSouvient souligne que, si le **coup de sonde** indique
>   que l’appui envers l’application de la loi est le plus important dans
>   la grande région de Montréal (84 %), il est aussi majoritaire dans
>   toutes les régions du Québec, quoique dans une moindre mesure : dans
>   l’est du Québec (78 %), dans le Centre (75 %) et dans l’Ouest (66 %).
>
> [ « [Les Québécois veulent l’application de la loi sur le registre des
>   armes, dit un sondage](https://www.ledevoir.com/societe/544845/registre-des-armes-les-quebecois-veulent-l-application-de-la-loi-dit-un-sondage) », *Le Devoir*, 5 janvier 2019, je souligne. ]

J'ai souvent vu cette association entre le [*sondage*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sondage) dans le domaine des statistiques et le *coup de [sonde](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sonde/0)*, le syntagme *donner un coup de sonde* étant de prime abord relié à la *sonde* pour l' « instrument composé d'un plomb fixé à l'extrémité d'une ligne servant à déterminer une hauteur d'eau et/ou la nature d'un fond aquatique ».

- Peut-on qualifier et expliquer pourquoi on a cet emploi du *coup de
  sonde* en statistiques plutôt qu'une référence par exemple à la «
  prise de sonde » (métonymique) et préciser la nature de l'association
  entre le *sondage* (statistiques) et *donner un coup de sonde* ;
  *sondage* et *coup de sonde* sont-ils synonymes ?

Comment: "[C]e sondage ... a été réalisé par la firme Léger" = Un sondage Léger = "Enquête/sondage rapide"= un coup de sonde? (Désolé, vu le nom de la firme réalisant ce sondage, je ne pouvais pas resister!)

Comment: @PapaPoule À l'origine c'était _Léger & Léger_, ça faisait donc deux coups, _wan wan_ ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Un peu comme le prétend [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34424/13100), je serais porté à percevoir le coup de sonde comme un sondage rapide, de peu d’envergure, à portée plus limitée, dont les résultats seront probablement un peu moins fiables. Il est principalement destiné à « tâter le terrain », à prendre le pouls, à discerner grossièrement les tendances, voir si une idée ou un produit répond à des attentes particulières, ou quelle idée ou produit se démarque à première vue parmi une certaine gamme (dans ce cas il pourrait être rapproché d’un dégrossissage).

Un type de sondage, donc, mais dans sa version la plus sommaire et rapide, pour un portrait statistique qui perdra un peu de précision mais permettra malgré tout, dans bien des cas, l’établissement de certains aspects de fond.

On pourrait penser à la différence entre un dessin et un croquis (qui est aussi un dessin, mais accompli en peu de temps et en laissant de côté bien des petits détails).

---

Mon premier jet (ci-dessus) était constituée de ma vision personnelle de la chose. Je ne suis pas tombé loin, mais il convient de mentionner des sources plus sûres lorsqu’elles existent, ce qui est bien le cas ici.

Au [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/sonde), nous avons :

> STATISTIQUES Sondage rapide effectué en constituant un échantillon d'unités à caractéristiques connues. *Lorsque l'on choisit a priori certaines unités, on dira plutôt que l'on effectue un* **coup de sonde** <sub>(Branc.Écon.1978).</sub>

Il semble bien que la rapidité (à la fois du sondage et de l’obtention de résultats) soit sous-entendue dans l’expression *« coup de sonde »*. On notera aussi le biais (assumé) d’un échantillon à caractéristiques connues.

La nature un peu *brouillon* (si j’ose dire) du coup de sonde peut porter à le considérer davantage comme un sondage d’intérêt privé plutôt que d’intérêt général, destiné à obtenir un portrait ponctuel caractéristique permettant de choisir une ligne d’action de manière mieux éclairée plutôt qu’à définir précisément et rigoureusement une caractéristique dans la population entière.

Un manufacturier qui effectue une enquête statistique **dans sa clientèle** afin de planifier les améliorations souhaitables de leurs produits, un parti politique qui demande à **ses membres** de s’exprimer sur tel sujet qui préoccupe la société en général, une enquête parmi les travailleurs **d’un secteur particulier** pour cerner leurs préoccupations en matière de santé et sécurité au travail.

La sonde permet dans son sens premier de mesurer les profondeurs d’eau. Statistiquement, on pourrait assimiler le coup de sonde à la mesure des profondeurs autour du bateau, et le sondage à l’établissement d’une carte bathymétrique d’une vaste région maritime ou d’un lac entier. Chacun possède son utilité, il convient simplement d’établir son choix en fonction de ses besoins.

Dans la réalité, il arrivera sans doute que l’on présente le coup de sonde comme un sondage, si l’on désire renforcer un argument, ou qu’au contraire l’on dévalorise les résultats d’un sondage comme étant ceux d’un simple coup de sonde dans une fraction déjà convaincue de la société, si l’on désire plutôt s’opposer à ce qu’ils affirment.

L’exemple de la question propose d’ailleurs un flou très curieux sur un sujet délicat. S’il s’agit d’un simple coup de sonde, qui en est le commenditaire ? Est-ce quelque groupe luttant pour le contrôle des armes à feu, tel que [PolySeSouvient](http://www.polysesouvient.ca/) ? Quelle caractéristique possède l’échantillon, que l’on peut certes supposer biaisé puisqu’il s’agit d’un simple coup de sonde ? Est-ce un public instruit, possédant des études universitaires, proportionnellement moins touché dans leurs passe-temps par ce type de contrôle ? Et pourquoi donc parler d’un simple coup de sonde si l’on désire convaincre du bien-fondé d’un registre du contrôle des armes à feu, ce qui semble bien dans le ton de l’atricle ? Ne devrait-on pas plutôt dire qu’il s’agit d’un sondage, en camouflant les caractéristiques un peu sommaires de l’enquête sous une appelation générale ?

Comment: @survenant9r7 Cette réponse n'est probablement pas traitée avec toute la rigueur désirée, ainsi que le démontre assez bien votre commentaire à l'autre réponse. Je verrai à inclure la nuance que vous y apportez. Merci et heureux de vous savoir de retour. Vos questions apportent une couleur particulière à ce site et sont toujours motivantes. Ne pas pouvoir consacrer suffisamment de temps pour répondre même à une petite portion de celles-ci ne change pas mon appréciation de votre esprit toujours curieux et plein de ressources.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Une fois de plus je me retrouve dans cette situation malaisante où je me déclare n'ayant pas été aux sources liées en question. Mes excuses. Je pencherais probablement comme vous pour la recherche de synonymes de la part du Devoir, sans forcément qu'on ait considéré l'expression comme faiblissant la portée du sondage mené, ce qui était un peu (selon moi) *se tirer dans le pied* (pour demeurer dans la métaphore du *coup de feu*).

Answer (score 1):

Le « coup de sonde » est une expression plutôt spécifique au Québec .

En France on utilisera le mot « sondage » dans le contexte d'une enquête visant à déterminer la répartition des opinions sur une question ( en recueillant des réponses auprès d'un échantillon de population.)

---

Mais « donner un coup de sonde », peut aussi être utilisé en Francais dans le sens de « Tester quelque chose, faire un essai, tâter le terrain. » ([source](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/18017/donner-un-coup-de-sonde/))

Depuis [la même source](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/18017/donner-un-coup-de-sonde/), il est dit:

> La sonde est, à l'origine, un instrument que l'on utilise pour
>   déterminer la profondeur d'une rivière ou d'une mer, ou que l'on
>   enfonce dans la terre pour connaître les propriétés d'un terrain.
>   Donner un coup de sonde consiste donc, avant de prendre un engagement
>   particulier, de tâter le terrain, d'évaluer par avance les chances de
>   succès de l'entreprise.

Comment: @Survenant9r7, j'ai nuancé la réponse pour être plus précis !

Comment: I grew up in Montreal, Quebec, am native french-speaking and went to Polytechnique (1998). Yet, I've never seen/heard "coup de sonde" before seeing this question. To me it sounds as something from France. My initial reaction was that this was written by someone from France studying at Polytechnique (mtl) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> La locution coup de sonde, qui s'emploie concrètement, a pris
>   figurément au XXe s. le sens de « rapide estimation d'opinion » (1935,
>   donner un coup de sonde) ; cette valeur métaphorique de sonde est déjà
>   attestée chez Chateaubriand (1802 [probablement le verbe soit [ici](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9), [ici](https://books.google.ca/books?id=PztAAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=G%C3%A9nie%20du%20christianisme&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=sonde&f=false) ou [ici](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Atala)]) et relève d'emplois antérieurs de sonder.
>
> [ Dictionnaire historique de la langue française, sup. Rey, chez
>   Robert, 2011 ]

---

> Lorsque l'on choisit a priori certaines unités, on dira plutôt que
>   l'on effectue un coup de sonde.
>
> [ [Michel Branciard](http://maitron-en-ligne.univ-paris1.fr/spip.php?article18440), né le 29 janvier 1926 à Gleize (Rhône), mort
>   le 31 janvier 2003 à Bourg-en-Bresse (Ain), ds. *Dictionnaire
>   économique et social* au TLFi à [sonde](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sonde/0). ]

Il n'y a pas plus français que ce Français-là. L'expression *coup de sonde* apparaît 66 fois sur le site [lemonde.fr](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=QkacXJ__I6Hm_QaioayYBw&q=site%3Awww.lemonde.fr%20%22coup%20de%20sonde%22&oq=site%3Awww.lemonde.fr%20%22coup%20de%20sonde%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...31527.33108..33448...1.0..0.60.278.5......0....1..gws-wiz.Vus61wrT5KU), 56 fois sur [lefigaro.fr](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=mUacXNLsBYHx_AaM0ZeQDQ&q=site%3Alefigaro.fr%20%22coup%20de%20sonde%22&oq=site%3Alefigaro.fr%20%22coup%20de%20sonde%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4044.4044..4302...0.0..0.58.58.1......0....1..gws-wiz.hHPnD-fwGWY), 20 fois sur [nouvelobs.com](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=site%3Anouvelobs.com%20%22coup%20de%20sonde%22) et une fois sur [courrierinternational.com](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=site%3Acourrierinternational.com%20%22coup%20de%20sonde%22) et dans ce dernier cas exactement dans le sens apparenté au sondage. Du coup le *coup de sonde* n'est pas une expression spécifique au Québec et en France on n'utilise pas « sondage » uniquement, indépendamment du sens. Mais là n'est pas la question.

---

En ce qui a trait à la première partie de la question uniquement, au TLFi on peut constater qu'on associe différents emplois du terme *sonde* à différentes sémantiques du verbe *sonder* et il faut remarquer qu'on trouve le *coup de sonde* relié autant à la détermination des qualités du fond aquatique qu'en prospection géologique (sous laquelle on range l'emploi en statistiques) alors que *prendre la sonde* relève davantage de la mesure de résultats que de l'action accomplie directement avec l'objet.

D'autre part le [*coup*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coup) n'implique pas nécessairement un choc : « [Avec une idée de simple mouvement] Mouvement d'un organe, d'une partie du corps, d'un élément et de tout ce qui est susceptible de servir d'instrument » (TLFi) et pourrait par ailleurs faire appel par extension à une idée d'« actionnement intermittent d'un instrument » ; l'intermittence se rattache aisément à la définition du *coup de sonde* en géologie « prospection d'un terrain en sondant en divers endroits pour repérer un gisement, déterminer la qualité, la nature de ce terrain » (*Lorsque l'on a lieu de craindre une brusque venue d'eau, on procède par coups de sonde divergents, poussés en avant des travaux* (E. Schneider,*Charbon*, 1945, p. 257))(TLFi).

---

Ça demeure une analyse spéculative... Au DHLF la réflexion est compliquée et il y a incertitude quant au fait que le verbe *sonder* dérive du nom *sonde* ou inversement ; une expertise plus grande est requise pour interpréter davantage le contenu et en tirer des conclusions pour l'autre partie de la question. Mais on retiendra que le *coup de sonde* pour la rapide estimation d'opinion est **un emploi au figuré avec une métaphore** de la sonde et qu'il n'y a donc pas lieu de retrouver une adéquation parfaite entre les moyens techniques et le sens de la locution.